# regex gives different results each run

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have the following code as part of a css preprocessor i am working on. This section takes user-defined variable and inserts them into the code. The regex only replaces if it surrounded by whitespace,braces, brackets, commas, quotes or operators. When I run it, I only get variables replaced every other time.

```
def insert_vars(ccss, variables):
    for var in variables.keys():
        replacer = re.compile(r"""(?P<before>[,+\[(\b{:"'])\$""" + var + """(?P<after>[\b}:"'\])+,])""")
        ccss = replacer.sub(r"\g<before>" + variables[var] + r"\g<after>", ccss)

        del replacer
        re.purge()

        return ccss.replace(r"\$", "$")
```

When I run it with

```
insert_vars("hello $animal, $nounification != {$noun}ification.", {"animal": "python", "noun": "car"})
```

50% of time it returns

```
hello $animal, $nounification != {car}ification.
```

the other 50%

```
hello $animal, $nounification != {$noun}ification.
```

Anybody have any idea why?

Comment: I was just thinking, why not?

Comment: Hmmm... I get `'hello $animal, $nounification != {car}ification.'` 100% of the time. Anyway, it looks like the `return` statement is part of the `for` loop: perhaps it should be moved outside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened was that your `return` keyword was part of the loop, as [acjr stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959548/regex-gives-different-results-each-run/25959724#comment40643897_25959548).

This means that the loop would only run for one iteration.

The ordering for `.keys()` is undefined, either `'animal'` or `'noun'` could come first.

Half of the time, your code would get `'noun'` first, which works correctly, or get `'animal'` first, which would have no effect.

Therefore, you should reduce the indentation of the `return` to be outside the loop.

Comment: I had also thought about that, but wasn't too sure, as I wnated the variables to be acessible using the $ syntax. I will maybe convert this to the format syntax.

Comment: @user229276 Ah, I had assumed that the user would only supply the variables, and not the source. I hadn't read the bit about css preprocessors.

Comment: @user229276 I have edited the answer to explain the problem with your current code.

Comment: Oh man, thanks. I had started to think there was something wierd with the python regex engine or something. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def insert_vars(ccss, variables):
    pattern = re.compile(r"\$(?P<key>\w+)")
    def replacer(match):
        return variables.get(match.group('key'), match.group(0))
    return pattern.sub(replacer, ccss)
```